# Ring Buffer in Java (Queue)

Tags: java, buffer

Could anyone explain me please, how a (linear) Ring Buffer in the context of Queues works? How to realize a queue using a ring buffer ? What is it good for ? Why does one use a ring buffer? Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

A circular buffer is useful for a FIFO (First-in-First-out) scenario and therefore a good implementation strategy for a queue with a fixed maximum size.

You usually have four pointers:

- one to the actual buffer in memory
- one to the buffer end in memory (or: the size of the buffer)
- one pointer to the start of valid data (i.e. index into an array)
- one pointer to the end of valid data. (i.e. index into an array)

Here is what happens when you add an element (uses an array):

- you add the element at the position of `(endindex + 1) %
  bufferSize`
- if you overwrite an element you need to also increment the `(startIndex + 1) % bufferSize`

When you overwrite or delete elements out of the buffer, you always do this to the element being the longest in the queue.

There are different use-cases that come along with this concept: One being for example an in-memory log.

For more implementation details please refer to: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at java.util.ArrayDeque implementation.